# X-Path - How To Pull This Field?

Tags: selenium, xpath

My code goes into a webpage, clicks on a record, which then drops other records.

Is there a way to use xPath to pull all of these drop-down titles?

Currently, I copied the first drop down titles full xpath, and its only pulling the first one.

That is fine, but how do I pull all entry titles that drop down?

My current code is specifically only for the first line

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for x in range (1,2):
    driver.get(f'https://library.iaslc.org/conference-program?product_id=24&author=&category=&date=&session_type=&session=&presentation=&keyword=&available=&cme=&page={x}')
    time.sleep(4)
    productlist_length = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordin_title']"))
    for i in range(1, productlist_length + 1):
        product = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='accordin_title'])[" + str(i) + "]")
        title = product.find_element_by_xpath('.//h4').text.strip()
        buttonToClick = product.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="sign"]') 
        buttonToClick.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        dropDownTitle=product.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="accordin"]/div/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li/div[1]/div[3]/h4').text #this line is the full xpath
        print(dropDownTitle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So can you check with the below line of code

```
#try to execute it in maximize mode sometimes element is overlayed

driver.maximize_window()
for x in range (1,5):
driver.get(f'https://library.iaslc.org/conference-program?product_id=24&author=&category=&date=&session_type=&session=&presentation=&keyword=&available=&cme=&page={x}')
time.sleep(4)
productlist_length = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordin_title']"))
for i in range(1, productlist_length + 1):
    product = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='accordin_title'])[" + str(i) + "]")
    title = product.find_element_by_xpath('.//h4').text.strip()
#So at some point the dropdown doesn't display any records so at that point it throws ClickInterceptedException, Also I ActionChain to move to the particular element
    buttonToClick = product.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="info_right"]/h4') 
   action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(buttonToClick).click().perform()
    time.sleep(5)
#Here if you just provide the index of the li it will print the title
    dropDownTitle=product.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='accordin']/div/ul/li["+str(i)+"]/div[1]/div[3]/h4").text 
    print(dropDownTitle)
```

**import**

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Output**
[image: titles]

Comment: lovely! Can i ask what libraries you have imported?

Comment: what method would you use to print the drop down titles ? Right now it prints the main records